# Ĉu oni estas "en" aŭ "sur" foto?

Tags: prepositions

Mi volus diri "sur foto" sed aliulo pensus ke tio signifus ke vi fizike staras sur printita foto. Tiu do dirus "en la foto" por priskribi la fotitojn. Ĉu estas regulo en Esperanto aŭ ĉu oni simple sekvas la manieron de sia denaska lingvo?

Answer (score 6):

Ambaŭ esprimoj estas bonaj kaj oftaj.

- En akompana foto la aŭtorino aperas kun Stina Katch ...
- vidu en la suba foto
- [La ladan tambureton] li prezentas en la supra foto
- Sur la foto maldekstre vi vidas 19-jaran litovon
- Sur la suba foto:
- (dekstre sur la foto)
- Sur la supra foto:

Estas klare ke en La Ondo de Esperanto oni preferas "sur". Mi mem diras "en" - sed la diferenco ne estas tiel grava.

Answer (score 4):

Se vi uzas *en*, vi parolas pri la foto aŭ bildo kvazaŭ imaga loko, *en kiu* homoj kaj objektoj staras fikse.

Se vi uzas *sur*, vi parolas pri la foto aŭ bildo kiel surfaco, *sur kiu* videblas io.

Komparu *sur la tablo* kun *sur la ĉielo*, aŭ *sur la muro* kun *sur la fenestro* (fojfoje = *fenestrobreto*).

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/sur.html